# Create new column with day of week using datetime

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to create a new column in this DataFrame with the name of the day of the week, but I can't. Does anyone have any tips?

```py
from datetime import date

days = [
  'Segunda-feira',
  'Terça-feira',
  'Quarta-feira',
  'Quinta-feira',
  'Sexta-feira',
  'Sábado',
  'Domingo'
  ]

import pandas as pd

vacinacao = pd.read_excel("vacinacao_br.xlsx")
vacinacao.head()

UF  Data Vacinacao  quantidade
0   AC  2021-01-18 00:00:00 1
1   AC  2021-01-19 00:00:00 46
2   AC  2021-01-20 00:00:00 1021
3   AC  2021-01-21 00:00:00 1609
4   AC  2021-01-22 00:00:00 1105

vacinacao['dia_semana'] = vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'].days.weekday.()

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `dtype` of your "Data Vacinado" column is some sort of `daytime`, you can use [dt.day_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html).

```py
vacinacao['dia_semana'] = vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'].dt.day_name()
```

NB: If the `dtype` of your column is a `str`, you'll have to convert your dates to `datetime` objects first:

```py
vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'] = pd.to_datetime(vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `dt` and not `days`

Try:

```
#for day number (0, 1, etc.)
vacinacao['dia_semana'] = vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'].dt.weekday

#for day full name (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)
vacinacao['dia_semana'] = vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'].dt.strftime("%A")

#for day short name (Mon, Tue, etc.)
vacinacao['dia_semana'] = vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'].dt.strftime("%a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up from your days list with .weekday() integer:

```
vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'] = pd.to_datetime(vacinacao['Data Vacinacao'],
                                             format="AC %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
vacinacao['dia_semana'] = [days[i.weekday()] for i in vacinacao['Data Vacinacao']]
```